# how to find out the outer property of a list

Tags: javascript, list, object

I have this list

```
myList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        slug: "fruits",
        title: "Fruits",
        types: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'mango',
                price: '200'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'grape',
                price: '500'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'banana',
                price: '200'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        slug: "veggies",
        title: "Veggies",
        types: [
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'brocolli',
                price: '200'
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                name: 'tomato',
                price: '500'
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Let's say I only have one information, which is the `id` of an object inside the `types` property. For example, I have grape with the id = 2. How can I know that `grape` is a part of the `fruits` object? I want to find the slug that is related to `grape`, which is `fruits`. I'm still confused with the logic here. Also sorry, if my question title is wrong, I don't know the keyword to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in order to search for a list inside a list.

```js
function findGroupFromTypeId(id, list) {
  const group = list.find(item => {
    return item.types.find(type => type.id === id) !== undefined;
  });
  if (group) {
    return group.slug;
  }
  return 'not found';
}

const myList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        slug: "fruits",
        title: "Fruits",
        types: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'mango',
                price: '200'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'grape',
                price: '500'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'banana',
                price: '200'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        slug: "veggies",
        title: "Veggies",
        types: [
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'brocolli',
                price: '200'
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                name: 'tomato',
                price: '500'
            }
        ]
    },
];

console.log(findGroupFromTypeId(1, myList));
console.log(findGroupFromTypeId(4, myList));
console.log(findGroupFromTypeId(999, myList));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
myList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        slug: "fruits",
        title: "Fruits",
        types: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'mango',
                price: '200'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'grape',
                price: '500'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'banana',
                price: '200'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        slug: "veggies",
        title: "Veggies",
        types: [
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'brocolli',
                price: '200'
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                name: 'tomato',
                price: '500'
            }
        ]
    },
]

function findSlug(list, typeId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var slugGroup = list[i]
        for (var j = 0; j < slugGroup.types.length; j++) {
            var typeInfo = slugGroup.types[j]
      
            if (typeInfo.id === typeId) {
                return slugGroup.slug
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(findSlug(myList, 2))
console.log(findSlug(myList, 5))
console.log(findSlug(myList, 8))
```